# Trying to make a 2d array program to store a list of Car objects

Tags: java, arrays

Struggling with a little project I've set myself to learn Java. My goal is to create a program to store a list of Car objects.  Then to allow the user to search for a particular car and output all of them if they exist.  The car object should contain model name, registration number, vin and colour. Here is what I have so far:

```
package carObjects;

public class cars {

    public static int length;
    private String modelName;
    private String carColour;
    private int regNumber;
    private int vin;

    public cars(String string, String string2, int i) {

    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Model Name: " + modelName + "Registration Number: " + regNumber
                + "Vin" + vin + "Car Colour:  " + carColour;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return modelName;
    }
}

        for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            cars[i] = new cars("A", "B", 10);
        }

        for (cars p : cars) {
            System.out.println(p.getLast());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what are struggling with?

Comment: what are your 2D array dimensions? By the way you are not using a 2D array.

Comment: Please improve the question, it is very unclear of what you want.
Refer to this to improve your question: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to separate your exercise in two different classes:

```
class Car {

    private String modelName;
    private String carColour;
    private int regNumber;
    private int vin;

    public int getVin() {
        return vin;
    }

    public void setVin(int vin) {
        this.vin = vin;
    }

    // other getter/setter

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car: " + getVin();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return vin;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj != null) 
            && (obj instanceof Car) 
            && ((Car) obj).getVin() == this.getVin();
    }
}
```

CarSet class has the searching methods:

```
class CarList extends HashSet<Car> {

    public Car serarchByVin(int vin) {
        List<Car> list = new ArrayList<>(this);
        for (Car c : list) {
            if (c.getVin() == vin) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public CarSet searchByModel(String model) {
        CarSet result = new CarSet();
        List<Car> list = new ArrayList<>(this);
        for (Car c : list) {
            if (c.getModelName()== model) {
                result.add(c);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "carList: ";
        for (Car c : this) {
            result += c;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the things you would need to do:

1. Since you want to allow searching, you will need to expose accessors to the properties which you would like the user to search for. For instance, if you want to allow users to search by model, you will need to expose the `model` property. You seem to be doing this through the `getLast()` method, however, the name is confusing.*
2. The problem with this code: `for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
       cars[i] = new cars("A", "B", 10);
   }`
   Is that it is creating a series of identical objects. You could use the value of `i` to provide some dummy, changing values. This will allow you to test that your search is indeed working.
3. Constructor names should start with an upper case, just like class names.
4. `cars(String string, String string2, int i)`: Please provide meaningful names to your variables. This will make your code easier to read.
5. You will need to assign the variables you are getting through your constructor. As is, at the moment your fields will not be initialized to what you are providing.
6. To create a 2D array, you will need to use the following syntax: `Car[][] carArr = new Car[5][5]`. This will create a `5x5` array of type car. To iterate over it, you will need to use a nested loop:

   for(int i = 0; i < carrArr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < carrArr[i].lenght;j++) {
            ...
        }
   }

`*` The usage of *getters* and *setters* allow you to control which object properties are exposed and how can users interact with them.